# Check if elements are sorted alphabetically in cypressIO

Tags: javascript, sorting, cypress

What is best practise when asserting that elements are sorted alphabetical using cypressIO?
I want to basically check that `element[0].text()` is correcly sorted before `element[1].text()` but for all elements like in the snippet below:

```
cy.get('#main div').each((account) => {

    });
  });
```

Comment: Does your code sort this list? Is the list sorted in a API somewhere? I ask because I am wondering if the test should be somewhere else. If it is coming from a API, I would probably mock it and check that it displays right.

Comment: What is the method that the accounts get sorted? What sorts them? A click on the screen, etc?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this or something similar will work for you (haven't tried it).  It is getting the text of all the elements that match the selector you provided and storing it in an array, then asserting that array matches before and after it is sorted.

```
cy.get('#main div').then($elements => {
  var strings = $elements.map($el => $el.text());
  cy.wrap(strings).should("equal", strings.sort()); // you may need deep equal here instead
});
```

Comment: Brendan will this same work for sorting of elements in a drop down list box ?

Comment: I have tried `cy.get('#cars_list').then($options => {
      var strings = $options.map($el => $el.text());
      cy.wrap(strings).should("equal", strings.sort()); 
    });`  but throws error >.TypeError: $el.text is not a function

Comment: I'm guessing `#cars_list` is not getting the individual elements that contain the text.  It's probably a parent element for all of them.  Post your HTML

Comment: <div class="wrapper">
<label>List of Cars to select</label>
<select id="cars_list">
<option  selected="selected" disabled="true">--Please Select --</option>
  <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
  <option value="saab">Saab</option>
  <option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
  <option value="audi">Audi</option>
  <option value="audi">Caten</option>
</select>
</div>

Comment: Change your selector to `#cars_list > option` so you are getting the individual elements

Comment: You'll have to do some research on getting text from elements, it's always a trick in cypress.  You could change it to work by value instead, since your `option` elements have a value attribute

Comment: Ahh why did i not come up with that:)  Your code did not work for me though. also got `.TypeError: $el.text is not a function` I did this and it worked:  `var accounts =[];
    cy.get('#main div').each(elements => {
      strings.push(elements.text());
    });
    cy.wrap(accounts).should("equal", accounts.sort());`

Answer (score 6):

There's a few gotcha's in Brendan's answer

- `$elements.map()` has two parameters in it's callback. The first is the ***index of the element*** in the jQuery object, not the element
- the second parameter is a DOM element, so `.text()` doesn't work, `innertText` is needed
- the result in `strings` can't be tested like an array since it's another `jQuery` object, it needs to be converted to an array before asserting
- the `cy.wrap(strings).should("equal", strings.sort())` is comparing the jQuery wrapper object to itself, giving a false positive result

This is the ***tested*** version that should have been posted

```js
cy.get('main#1 div')
  .should($elements => {
    const strings = $elements.map((index, el) => el.innerText).get()
    return strings
  })
  .should('deep.eq', ['a', 'b', 'c'])
```

Test HTML:

```html
<main id="1">
  <div>a</div>
  <div>b</div>
  <div>c</div>
</main>

<main id="2">
  <div>c</div>
  <div>b</div>
  <div>a</div>
</main>

<main id="3">
  <div>b</div>
  <div>c</div>
  <div>a</div>
</main>
```

---

See [jQuery .map()](https://api.jquery.com/map/)

> **callback**
> Type: Function( Integer index, Element domElement ) => Object

Answer (score 2):

Solution that will work on Cypress 7.x

```js
cy.get('#main div').then($elements => {
  const strings = [...$elements].map(el => el.innerText)
  expect(strings).to.deep.equal([...strings].sort())
})
```

Reasoning:

- jQuery `.map` works in different way than vanilla JS `.map`, because it takes parameters in different order (`index, el` instead of `el, index`) and does not return a pure array, which is needed for future sorting. That's why the jQuery elements list is spread to pure array.
- `Array.sort()` works in-place, so array need to be cloned before sorting, otherwise it will compare the same data.
- To compare values of an array, deep comparison is needed, so usage of the Chai syntax with `expects` and `deep.equal` is required.

Comment: Sounds good but where does `list` come from?

Comment: @Sarah good catch, typo, should be `strings`

Comment: Great answer, thanks for walking us through the 3 crucial steps to make this work reliably in both directions! I accidentally overlooked the cloning part at first and instead came up with `expect(\`${strings}\`).to.equal(\`${strings.sort()}\`)`, but your solution makes the intention more clear for the reader imho.